# What is the C# way equivalent of this for loop?

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, compiler-errors

I'm very new to C#, learning the elements of it day by day, coming from C also confuses me because a simple for loop such as this would work, so why doesn't it work in C#, if you could explain in detail (if possible) I would greatly appreciate it.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){

    public void question()
    {
        if (questionNr == 1)
        {
            questionLabel.Text = "What is Chuck's full name?";
            ans1.Text = "Charles Irving Bartowski";
            ans2.Text = "Charles Richard Bartowski";
            ans3.Text = "Charles Luke Bartowski";
            ans4.Text = "Zachary Strahovski";
        }
        else if (questionNr == 2)
        {
            questionLabel.Text = "Who/what is Orion?";
            ans1.Text = "Original name of the Intersect";
            ans2.Text = "Alias of a secret mission";
            ans3.Text = "Morgan's Xbox";
            ans4.Text = "Chuck's father";
        }

    }

    public void ans1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (questionNr == 1)
        {
            pointCounter++;
            pointsLabel.Text = "Current points:" + pointCounter.ToString();
            questionNr++;
        }


    }

    private void ans2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (questionNr == 1)
        {
            questionNr++;
        }
    }

    private void ans3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (questionNr == 1)
        {
            questionNr++;
        }
    }

    private void ans4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (questionNr == 1)
        {
            questionNr++;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: That would not work in C either

Comment: What do you want this to do?

Answer (score 7):

The lexical structure of a C# file must be:

```
namespace
    class
        method
            statement
```

A `for` is a statement but you have placed it outside the method. Put it inside the method.

Answer (score 5):

No.. that wouldn't work.

You're declaring methods inside of a loop body. That isn't valid in C#.. or C as far as I am aware. It certainly isn't in C++.

I apologise for not giving you a working fix for this.. but I honestly cannot see what you're trying to do.

Comment: Then maybe this should have been a comment?

Answer (score 3):

Methods can not be declared inside of a loop. Try moving the methods outside of the loop, and calling them from the loop. Like this:

```
public void firstMethod()
{
    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {
        aMethod();//call the method "aMethod()" 10 times
    }
}
//outside of the method containing the loop
public void aMethod() {
    //do some stuff in the method
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `for` loop is containing the whole class it seems.  Try this:

```
public void question()
{

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
        if (questionNr == 1)
        {
            questionLabel.Text = "What is Chuck's full name?";
            ans1.Text = "Charles Irving Bartowski";
            ans2.Text = "Charles Richard Bartowski";
            ans3.Text = "Charles Luke Bartowski";
            ans4.Text = "Zachary Strahovski";
        }
        else if (questionNr == 2)
        {
            questionLabel.Text = "Who/what is Orion?";
            ans1.Text = "Original name of the Intersect";
            ans2.Text = "Alias of a secret mission";
            ans3.Text = "Morgan's Xbox";
            ans4.Text = "Chuck's father";
        }
    }
}

public void ans1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (questionNr == 1)
    {
        pointCounter++;
        pointsLabel.Text = "Current points:" + pointCounter.ToString();
        questionNr++;
    }


}

private void ans2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (questionNr == 1)
    {
        questionNr++;
    }
}

private void ans3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (questionNr == 1)
    {
        questionNr++;
    }
}

private void ans4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (questionNr == 1)
    {
        questionNr++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Whilst this would compile.. it seems pretty useless.

Comment: I agree.  But at least it compiles!  There's no reference to `i` so it's anyone's guess as to where the `for` loop should go :)

Comment: Yeah, I saw his previous question from about 1 hour ago and I am pretty sure the Answer I supplied will do what he is looking for.  He does not need a for loop at all

Answer (score 2):

As I saw your previous question let me elaborate on what I stated there.  I am sure when the user selects an answer you wish to go to the next question.  If this is the case just have the `Event Handler` increment `questionNr`.  The only stipulation is if it is the last question, then you need to handle that event (`questionNr == 10`).  In your `Event Handler` after you `increment` then call your `Question` method from before.  In your `Question` Method you have a `switch` statement on `questionNr` and change the values of the `textbox` accordingly.  I know I am not supplying you code, but I commented on your first question about this, so I am referencing your original code.

Ok I changed my mind and will add the code :)

**Question Method:**

```
public void question()
{
    switch(questionNr)
    {
        case 1:
            questionLabel.Text = "What is Chuck's full name?";
            ans1.Text = "Charles Irving Bartowski";
            ans2.Text = "Charles Richard Bartowski";
            ans3.Text = "Charles Luke Bartowski";
            ans4.Text = "Zachary Strahovski";
        break;
        case 2:
            questionLabel.Text = "Who/what is Orion?";
            ans1.Text = "Original name of the Intersect";
            ans2.Text = "Alias of a secret mission";
            ans3.Text = "Morgan's Xbox";
            ans4.Text = "Chuck's father";
        break;
        case 3:
        break;
        // More and More Questions.
    }
}
```

**Answer Button Click Event:**

```
public void ans1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    questionNr++
    this.question();
    // Whatever else you need to do
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have function definitions inside of a for loop, in either language. For loops and other control structures must be inside of a function, and functions must be inside of a class.

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){

    Action question = () =>
    {
        //Method Body

    };

    //...
}
```

Or use delegates depending what version of c# you are using, but I think it's better to use c# style and conventions when writing c#.

edit*
A lot of people are saying you cannot have functions within a for loop which is incorrect.  Assume for instance you are attaching handlers to a large group of controls you can create a function using Func or a method using Action. Reference  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System(v=vs.110).aspx